# breaking up line chart in flex charting

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe, flex-charting

I am wondering how will i proceed with the following requirement. I need to create a line chart of business data of the last 8 quarters. It is easy, but the requirement is that, there should not be a connection between last year's Q4 and this years Q1. In effect, using the same array collection i need to split the line chart so that it looks like two diffferent lines on the same chart. Any idea how to proceed with it.

Thanks, PK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you can add multiple line series by a criteria in your Array Collection:

```
<mx:series>
           <mx:LineSeries 
                yField="Profit" 
                displayName="Profit"
           />
           <mx:LineSeries 
                yField="Expenses" 
                displayName="Expenses"
           />
        </mx:series>
```

You can change the width and color of the lines for each series by using the  tag. Making each line a different stroke and color.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!-- charts/BasicLineStroke.mxml -->
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml">
  <mx:Script><![CDATA[
     import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
     [Bindable]
     public var expenses:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection([
        {Month:"Jan", Profit:2000, Expenses:1500, Amount:450},
        {Month:"Feb", Profit:1000, Expenses:200, Amount:600},
        {Month:"Mar", Profit:1500, Expenses:500, Amount:300}
     ]);
  ]]></mx:Script>
  <mx:Panel title="Line Chart With Strokes">
     <mx:LineChart id="myChart" 
        dataProvider="{expenses}" 
        showDataTips="true"
     >
        <mx:horizontalAxis>
           <mx:CategoryAxis 
                dataProvider="{expenses}" 
                categoryField="Month"
            />
        </mx:horizontalAxis>
        <mx:series>
           <mx:LineSeries 
            yField="Profit" 
            displayName="Profit"
           >
            <mx:lineStroke>
                <mx:Stroke 
                    color="0x0099FF" 
                    weight="20" 
                    alpha=".2"
                />
            </mx:lineStroke>                
           </mx:LineSeries>
           <mx:LineSeries 
            yField="Expenses" 
            displayName="Expenses"
           >
            <mx:lineStroke>
                <mx:Stroke 
                    color="0x0044EB" 
                    weight="20" 
                    alpha=".8"
                />
            </mx:lineStroke>                
           </mx:LineSeries>
        </mx:series>
     </mx:LineChart>
     <mx:Legend dataProvider="{myChart}"/>
  </mx:Panel>
</mx:Application>
```